# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to handle this TypeError in my program. I'm getting a TypeError within this function

```
    # Function will get the distances between current location and next package's delivery address.
def find_distance(current_address, package_address):
    if find_address(package_address) > find_address(current_address):
        current_distance = distance_data[find_address(package_address)][
            find_address(current_address)]
    else:
        current_distance = distance_data[find_address(current_address)][
            find_address(package_address)]
    return current_distance
```

The function calls another function find_address()

```
   def find_address(address):
    i = 0
    while i < len(address_data):
        if address == address_data[i][1]:
            return i
        else:
            i = i + 1


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DeNyus Keys\PycharmProjects\C950\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    start_trucks(timedelta(hours=-0))
  File "C:\Users\DeNyus Keys\PycharmProjects\C950\trucks.py", line 32, in start_trucks
    run_routes(truck1, time)
  File "C:\Users\DeNyus Keys\PycharmProjects\C950\trucks.py", line 48, in run_routes
    new_distance = find_distance(current_location, package_address)  # Calls find_distance() function
  File "C:\Users\DeNyus Keys\PycharmProjects\C950\trucks.py", line 77, in find_distance
    if find_address(package_address) > find_address(current_address):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The find_address() function returns an int that is the packages ID number so I don't know where the 'Nonetype' is coming from.  Any ideas?  Thank you guys a lot for any help.  I hope I put enough code to understand the issue.

Comment: It certainly returns `None` when it can't find a matching address in the `address_data`.

Comment: The error message says that the first call `find_address(package_address)` returns None. That happens if `while i < len(address_data):` completes without finding anything and the function ends with the default return value of None.

Comment: So, what should happen when `find_address` doesn't find an address?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for failure is your `address_data` does not have an entry for `package_address` passed, so what can you do is if any of the address is absent in `address_data` return saying Unable to calculate distance.

```
def find_distance(current_address, package_address):
    package_address = find_address(package_address)
    current_address = find_address(current_address)
    if not package_address or not current_address:
        return "Unable to get the distance between the address"

    if find_address(package_address) > find_address(current_address):
        current_distance = distance_data[find_address(package_address)][
            find_address(current_address)]
    else:
        current_distance = distance_data[find_address(current_address)][
            find_address(package_address)]
    return current_distance
```

Answer (score 0):

After learning to use the debugger a bit, I found out that the package_address being used was `"2010 West 500 S"` whereas the address in the CSV loader it was referencing was `"2010 West 500 South"`.  Once I renamed it to match exactly, the program runs.